# Automatically load a webpage based on Watson Assistant context

Tags: javascript, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to have an app orchestrate specific web pages depending on the context within a Watson Assistant dialogue.

The files I am using are an edit of the Watson Assistant (intermediate) sample files on github (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-intermediate).

Here is the snippet of the code (within api.js) I have edited to get this to work:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', messageEndpoint, true);
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200 && http.responseText) {
    Api.setResponsePayload(http.responseText);

var json = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
        context = json.context;

          if(json.context.action === 'SocialMedia') {

          document.getElementById("payload-column").setAttribute("style", "background-color: #ffffff;") //renders background white as without this line the webpage comes back with black hidden text for some reason
          document.getElementById("payload-column").setAttribute("src", "https://www.csc2.ncsu.edu/faculty/healey/tweet_viz/tweet_app/?q=" + json.context.AnalysisSearchItem);

          }
```

and the corresponding configuration within Watson Assistant workspace is:

```
{
  "context": {
    "action": "SocialMedia"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Loading sentiment analysis from the Computer Science department of North Carolina State University..."
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

I am connected to the Watson Assistant workspace as the normal chatbot dialogue works, and the

```
document.getElementById("payload-column").setAttribute("src", "https://www.csc2.ncsu.edu/faculty/healey/tweet_viz/tweet_app/?q=" + json.context.AnalysisSearchItem);
```

line on its own does change the iframe to the website I want (I have defined an iframe in the index.html file), its just that the IF condition

```
if(json.context.action === 'SocialMedia')
```

is not succesfully executed when the context falls under SocialMedia.

Would be very grateful if anyone can help how to resolve the issue....!